# Aggregate result of sub query to comma separated values

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

How to get get the result of subquery as comma separated values.

I have three tables , `location` and `stock_location_type` and `location_label`.

I am joining location and stock_location_type and based on the result of `SLT.inventory_location_cd` , I am querying another table `location_label`.

To do that I am writing following query.

```
select L.stock_catalogue_id, SLT.inventory_location_cd,
       case
           when nventory_location_cd = 'base location' then  (select related_location_id from location_label where base_location_id = location_id)
           when nventory_location_cd != 'base location' then (select base_location_id from location_label where related_location_id = location_id)
           end as "Current Location",
       * from location L
join stock_location_type SLT on L.stock_location_type_id = SLT.stock_location_type_id;
```

These subquueries returns multiple rows.

I tried using string_agg and casting related_location_id and base_location_id (as they are UUIDs). But then it complains about group by.

If I use group by then it errors out , `'multiple rows returned by subquery'`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [string_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) function to aggregate the values in a comma-separated string. So your sub-queries needs to be rewritten to

```
select string_agg(related_location_id, ', ') from location_label where base_location_id = location_id
```

and

```
select string_agg(base_location_id, ', ') from location_label where related_location_id = location_id
```

Answer (score 2):

I recreated your set of tables with

A `location_label` table

```
create table location_label(location_id int, location_label varchar);
insert into location_label values(1, 'Home');
insert into location_label values(2, 'Office');
insert into location_label values(3, 'Garage');
insert into location_label values(4, 'Bar');
```

A `stock_location_type` table

```
create table stock_location_type (stock_location_type_id int, inventory_location_cd varchar);
insert into stock_location_type values(1, 'base location');
insert into stock_location_type values(2, 'Not base location');
```

A `location` table

```
create table location (stock_catalogue_id int, base_location_id int, related_location_id int, stock_location_type_id int);

insert into location values(1,1,2,1);
insert into location values(1,2,1,2);
insert into location values(1,3,3,1);

insert into location values(2,4,3,1);
insert into location values(2,3,1,1);
insert into location values(2,2,4,2);
```

If I understand your statement correctly you are trying to join `location` and `location_label` tables based on the `inventory_location_cd` column using either `base_location_id` or `location_id`.

If this is what you're trying to achieve, the following query should do it. By moving the join condition in the proper place

```
select L.stock_catalogue_id, 
 SLT.inventory_location_cd, 
 location_id "Current Location Id",
 location_label "Current Location Name"
from location L join stock_location_type SLT 
on L.stock_location_type_id = SLT.stock_location_type_id
left outer join location_label 
on (
  case when 
    inventory_location_cd = 'base location' 
  then base_location_id 
  else related_location_id 
  end) = location_id
;
```

result is

```
 stock_catalogue_id | inventory_location_cd | Current Location Id | Current Location Name 
--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------
                  1 | base location         |                   1 | Home
                  1 | Not base location     |                   1 | Home
                  1 | base location         |                   3 | Garage
                  2 | base location         |                   3 | Garage
                  2 | base location         |                   4 | Bar
                  2 | Not base location     |                   4 | Bar
(6 rows)
```

if you need to aggregate it up by `stock_catalogue_id` and `inventory_location_cd`, that can be achieved with

```
select L.stock_catalogue_id, 
 SLT.inventory_location_cd,
 string_agg(location_id::text, ',') "Current Location Id",
 string_agg(location_label::text, ',') "Current Location Name"
from location L join stock_location_type SLT 
 on L.stock_location_type_id = SLT.stock_location_type_id
 left outer join location_label 
 on (case when inventory_location_cd = 'base location' then base_location_id else related_location_id end) = location_id
group by L.stock_catalogue_id, 
 SLT.inventory_location_cd;
```

with the result being

```
 stock_catalogue_id | inventory_location_cd | Current Location Id | Current Location Name 
--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------
                  1 | base location         | 1,3                 | Home,Garage
                  1 | Not base location     | 1                   | Home
                  2 | base location         | 3,4                 | Garage,Bar
                  2 | Not base location     | 4                   | Bar
(4 rows)
```